# Зависает ПО при работе с mysql

Tags: mysql

Таблица в БД сейчас весит 87 гиг, при любых запросах к ней HeidiSQL и любые другие ПО что я пробовал вешаются, в том числе и при попытке вывести инфу в браузер. Получается сделать запрос только при наличие LIMIT, но в этом случае мне нужна сортировка по столбцу с типом timestamp, когда я пытаюсь отсортировать, то ПО вешается даже с наличием LIMIT 5, подскажите что можно сделать? Вариант уменьшения таблицы или бекапированию в другую не подходит.

Comment: К сожалению чудес не бывает, нужно уменьшать размер таблицы. Шардинг + индексы должны помочь.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov подскажите, почему ПО вешается при order by по полю timestamp, неужели перелопачивает всю таблицу не смотря на limit ?

Comment: Конечно. Ведь чтобы найти N (указанный в `LIMIT`) самых больших значений, при отсутствии соответствующих индексов надо просмотреть весь набор данных. Иначе нет никакой гарантии, что они действительно самые большие. Другое дело индексы, они заранее упорядочивают значения указанных полей и позволяют осматривать не всё. Это не "бесплатная производительность", это дополнительные записи, но обычно стоит того.

Comment: Если индексов нет, то скорее всего так и выходит. Сами подумайте, как можно получить top 100 элементов по какому то значению как минимум  не  прочитав один раз весь набор

Comment: @D-side, не совсем понимаю, поле по которому сортирую создан индекс.

Comment: Из вопроса это не следует, но раз так, делайте `EXPLAIN` вашего запроса. С глупыми ошибками оптимизатора MySQL сталкивался даже я, со своим крошечным опытом работы с ним. Иногда советовать использовать индексы нужно явно.

Comment: @D-side я сделал, что дает EXPLAIN ? У меня есть выход кроме уменьшения размера таблицы?

Comment: EXPLAIN показывает план запроса и используемые индексы.

Comment: @D-side я вижу что когда делаю order by по id то в поле key я вижу PRIMARY если делаю order by по полю с датой время то вижу null, это значит что на этом поле нету индекса?

Comment: Скорее всего. Только вы выше утверждали, что он есть?..

Comment: @D-side, да потому что смотрел вот через heidisl. Посмотрите пожалуйста вот 2 скриншота
https://yadi.sk/i/R6zm6GxxuJSsg
https://yadi.sk/i/aufTtMUeuJStb

Comment: Если я правильно интерпретирую вывод этой софтины, то у вас два **составных** индекса, и в обоих `time` не является **первым** полем. Поэтому даже если использовать индекс, придётся в любом из этих двух индексов обшаривать все группы по первому полю. Оптимизатор, видимо, решил, что это будет не быстрее, чем обойти всю таблицу. Возможно, он даже прав.

Comment: @D-side в это таблице сейчас 309 000 000 записей, что же мне делать? Если уменьшу до 20 000 000 решится проблема с производительностью? Таблица весит 89 гиг.

Comment: Меньше данных -- меньше обходить. Это, конечно, решение, но скучное. Можно посоветовать оптимизатору индекс. Или сделать другой, более подходящий. Или переделать один из существующих.

Comment: @D-side как бы вы поступили? Как мне повесить индекс на поле time что бы оно нормально сортировалось и можно было его использовать в where?

Comment: Как я бы поступил, вам неинтересно, т. к. я не использовал бы MySQL :] Попробуйте разные варианты, вы ничего толком не теряете. Можете ещё и сами ответ написать (ещё один), если найдёте устраивающее решение.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такой костыль:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `table` order by id DESC LIMIT 1000) AS `sorted` ORDER BY `time` DESC
```